# Bloquear ataque javascript e sql-injection na mesma string

Tags: javascript, php, sql-injection, xss

Estou a receber dados de um formulário no php via get.

Estou a tratar a informação da seguinte maneira:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_GET["t"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Com isso pretendo bloquear ataques por javascript e sql-injection.

As dúvidas são:

- É a melhor forma de bloquear esses dois tipos de ataques?
- htmlspecialchars poderia anular de alguma forma a eficácia da função mysql_real_escape_string?

Já li diversos tópicos sobre esses assuntos, mas cada um diz uma coisa e nem sempre é possível verificar se a informação é confiável ou não.

Comment: [Sobre sql injection](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-injecao-de-codigo-sql-no-meu-codigo-php) e [xss](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10921/ataques-xss-como-ocorre)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Possível duplicata dessa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-injecao-de-codigo-sql-no-meu-codigo-php

Comment: @perdeu a pergunta é diferente, coloquei 2 perguntas no fim que não são respondidas no tópico mencionado.

Comment: @Bacco a pergunta é diferente, coloquei 2 perguntas no fim que não são respondidas no tópico mencionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) ou [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) são melhores para verificação disso. Confira o artigo [Evite SQL Injection usando Prepared Statements no PHP](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/evite-sql-injection-usando-prepared-statements-no-php).

*Outro fator é que **`mysql_`*** está depreciado nas versões mais novas do PHP.

Muito importante é na recuperação, em vez de utilizar `$_GET` ou `$_POST`, utilize [**`filter_input()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php).

Comment: Obrigado pelos links, mas coloquei 2 perguntas e só a primeira foi respondida, sabe alguma coisa sobre a segunda? Obrigado.

Comment: Bom @Filipe, a segunda automaticamente foi respondida, porque, o uso mysql_real_escape_string seria já inapropriado pelo fator Deprecate do Mysql_ como já tinha respondido no primeiro, isso é um fator de segurança. Agora, é boa prática utilizar a rotina desenvolvida para isso que seria somente mysql_real_escape_string ou mysql_espace_string, eu sempre utilizei assim e nunca tive problema, apesar que hoje utilizo PDO com prepare e o mesmo faz o trabalho de proteção. Um outra coisa seria utilizar **filter_input** em vez de $_GET e $_POST eu edite o post e lá tem o link por favor leia o assunto

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo, fiquei esclarecido.

Answer (score 1):

Proteger contra XSS e SQL injection ao mesmo tempo pode ser uma tarefa bem complicada e potencialmente com muitos pega ratões que só alguém com perícia em DOM e em SQL pode ter ideia do risco. Contra SQLi, a documentação é farta, porém pensem as seguintes situações aonde javascript pode ser executado:

Propriedades como onload, onclick, onblur (...) permitem executar javascript

> < img src="xpto.gif" onload="alert('XSS!')"/>

URLs podem executar javascript com prefixo "javascript:"

> < a href="javascript:alert('XSS');">Ola Mundo< /a>

Recomendo leitura do documento https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet. **Existem centenas de modos de, mesmo ao usar um filtro contra SQLi, salvar no banco de dados uma string que será um problema de XSS quando for visualizada**.

### O que fazer?

O modo mais simples de ter certeza que evita SQLi e XSS ao mesmo tempo é, além de usar funções nativas e bem conhecidas contra SQLi, e fazer um filtro agressivo. Se um campo somente aceita inteiro, remover tudo que não for número. Se são letras e números, filtrar para apenas isso. E, mais importante, **evitar aceitar HTML numa entrada do usuário**.

Se realmente tiver que aceitar HTML, deverá ou usar uma biblioteca pronta que remova todas as referências a Javascript do código, ou então fazer uma lista branca de que tags são permitidas e quais propriedades de tags são permitidas, o que não é trivial.