# Select no MySQL ignorando aspas simples

Tags: javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, select

Olá
Como posso utilizar este select e ignorar valor com aspa simples?

```
.
.
.st.executeQuery("select * from tabela_A where id = uc");

        rs = st.getResultSet();


        while (rs.next()) {

                texto = rs.getString("rua")
           }...
```

...o problema é que quando a rua é por exemplo Passo'Dareia, quero eliminar esta aspa simples, pois caso contrario terei um erro na sequencia do sistema...

ps. o select está sendo feito no MYSQL, e o retorno(rs.getString) utilizado em uma pagina JSP.

Comment: Qual erro por exemplo? Você quer eliminar no retorno ou pode ser depois, dentro da variável texto mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tratar o retorno logo no resultado.

```
texto = rs.getString("rua");
if (null != texto) {
  texto = texto.replaceAll("\'","");
}
```

Comment: Pra que a contrabarra?

Comment: Contrabarra serve para escapar o caractere e ser aceita como está sendo usada. Não funcionaria sem ela.

Comment: O replaceAll recebe uma expressão regular (RegEx), então é necessário  escapar a aspa simples.

Comment: @ricktg Mas não é melhor usar `texto.replace("'", "")`? Qual seria a justificativa pra usar expressão regular?

Comment: Não é melhor, nem pior pois os dois metodos usam o Pattern e Matcher para efetuar a busca. Na minha opinião o regex é mais assertivo na busca do char.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era isso mesmo...funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

você tem que tratar essa entrada colocando uma função para colocar \' (contra barra) nas aspas e elementos que podem interferir na consulta sql.

Acredito que esse link [Bloquear ataque javascript e sql-injection na mesma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12767/bloquear-ataque-javascript-e-sql-injection-na-mesma-string) possa te ajudar.