# Arquivo PHP requisitado pelo jQuery responder apenas para o próprio domínio

Tags: php, ajax, segurança, cors

Fiz um código `.ajax()` do jQuery para evitar acesso direto aos arquivos PHP, porém gostaria de melhorar a segurança dos arquivos PHP requisitados, li sobre *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* e outras dicas, porém pesquisei e não obtive uma explicação/exemplo de código com clareza.

Nos arquivos PHP onde a requisição é feita por `.ajax()` do jQuery, existe o código no início para evitar acesso direto:

```
<?php
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');

if(!IS_AJAX) {die('Acesso restrito');}

$pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],getenv('HTTP_HOST'));

if($pos===false)
  die('Acesso restrito');
?>
```

A solicitação é feita assim:

```
<button class='btn btn-default' id='btnGravarRegistro'>Gravar</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnGravarRegistro").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST', 
            url: "ajax/cadastro",
            data: $('#formCad').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#return').html(data);
            }
    });
</script>
```

Como melhorar as validações para evitar acesso direto e injection de códigos?

Comment: [O que é o PHP Injection? Qual a diferença dele para o SQL Injection? E como evitá-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699).

Comment: no MSSQL como DB usado, tudo é feito com procedure, com regras e validações de tipo de dados na própria procedure, as regras e tudo mais, porém a preocupação é com o código do site, em requisições diretas ou modos de burlar esse código básico que implementei.

Comment: Veja também: [Ataques XSS, como ocorre?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10931/60376).