# É possível executar um código em JavaScript após redirecionamento de página?

Tags: javascript, html, redirecionamento

Acabei um curso online de JavaScript e resolvi criar um simples programa que me possibilite abrir a página da *Google* com o background do `<body>` na cor preta.

A minha ideia foi realizar um redirecionamento com a função `location.assign` e depois modificar a página usando o `document`, dessa forma:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dark Google</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            location.assign("https://www.google.com");
            //Tentei também esse código: window.open("https://www.google.com","_self");
            document.body.style.background = "#000";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pesquisei muito na internet sobre isso antes de vir perguntar aqui, mas não obtive sucesso nas minhas buscas.

Então minha pergunta é, como posso executar um código em JavaScript após redirecionar para uma página sem precisar abrir o famoso console do browser e escrever o código manualmente ?

Comment: Agradeço imensamente se conseguirem responder minha pergunta e se alguém achou minha pergunta ruim, seria possível me explicarem o que há de errado nela para eu poder corrigi-la ?

Comment: Só utilizando bom senso, acredito que a resposta seja não, não é possível. Permitir que um código arbitrário de um domínio seja executado num outro domínio sem nenhum tipo de permissão, é uma falha de segurança gravíssima.

Comment: Se quer fazer isso, sugiro ter um iframe dentro do body e carregar a página que quiser lá, daí você pode personalizar essa página pelo código da sua página

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É impossível, pelo menos por meio dos navegadores atuais, executar scripts em uma página a qual o usuário será redirecionado. Pelo menos é para ser, já que podem existir *falhas* ou explorações maliciosas não conhecidas que permitam que isso seja feito.

E essa impossibilidade se dá por razões de segurança. Imagine se fosse possível executar scripts no site para o qual redirecionaria meu usuário. Seria, nessa situação hipotética, possível levar o usuário a sites como de bancos e executar scripts lá. Você literalmente poderia modificar qualquer site sem nem o programador original saber, e nem preciso dizer o quão problemático isso é. Por isso digo que é para ser *impossível*.

---

Contudo, se você é a pessoa que mantém o site ao qual você quer redirecionar, você pode criar maneiras de fazer com que isso seja possível. O modo mais simples de atingir algo assim é criar uma lista de scripts **pré-determinados** e, com base em algum parâmetro passado na URL, determinar qual script será executado. Por exemplo, você poderia criar um código no *back-end* do seu site que faz o *append* de um `<script>` antes do final da sua página para executar alguma coisa.

Imagine que você deseja redirecionar um usuário a uma outra página do **seu** site. Você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
window.location.replace('https://example.com/some-page?script=1);
```

E com base naquele `1` na query `script` inserir um script **pré-determinado** ao final da página HTML. E você pode criar uma lista com vários IDs pré-determinados por você. Cada um poderá renderizar alguma coisa pré-determinada no final da página.

Se você estiver utilizando PHP, pode ser algo assim:

```php
<!-- O resto da sua página para cima... -->

<?php
  // Note que estamos comparando o valor que recebemos do usuário
  // (valor esse que não é confiável) através de uma string pré-determinada
  // por nós. No caso, esse ID 1, que irá renderizar um script pré-determinado.
  //
  // Nunca permita que um parâmetro passado pelo usuário seja executado. E se por
  // acaso houver essa necessidade (o que não é o caso aqui e na maioria das vezes),
  // certifique-se de fazer uma grande e minuciosa validação e outros cuidados com
  //  o valor passado.
  if ($_GET['script'] === '1') {
    echo '<script>';
    // Você já sabe o que tem nesse arquivo `meu-script-1.js` e sabe que
    // o usuário não poderá usá-lo de forma a quebrar a segurança.
    // Esse script foi pré-criado por você e tem meras funções de "efeitos"
    // programados por você, o administrador do site.
    echo file_get_contents('./meu-script-1.js');
    echo '</script>';
  }
?>

<!-- O resto da sua página para baixo... -->
```

Devo enfatizar a necessidade desses scripts os quais referi serem **pré-determinados**. Você **NUNCA** deve permitir que o usuário execute scripts arbitrários em suas páginas. Quando algum site não se protege contra isso, chama-se vulnerabilidade XSS ([*cross-site scripting*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)), que é extremamente grave. Portanto, se você quiser implementar algo assim, leia muito sobre isso para não criar uma vulnerabilidade acidentalmente por falta de atenção com a segurança. Um bom lugar para começar a entender como o XSS funciona é [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10921/69296).